# What is "git de-duplicates blobs"?

Tags: git

I was reading [this blog post](https://kate.io/blog/git-bomb/) about git bombs and came across the concept of git de-duplicates blobs to make repositories smaller. Unfortunately the article doesn't explain in a clear way or maybe doesn't go into details about what does it exactly mean or how it actually works.

Can i please get a clear explanation of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a linux background you can think of de-duplication as hard links.

A git repository contains an object database. This is the place where all your files, directories and commit messages are stored at.

When git stores a file in the object database it hashes the file using a SHA-1 hash. Then it stores the file under this hash so that it can be looked up using the hash (a 40 character checksum).

Thus all objects that have equal content will produce the same hash. Since the content is equal git will save the object only once. That is **de-duplication**.

---

**The git bomb repository**

The git bomb repository, that is mentioned in the blog you posted, makes use of de-duplication to create a very small repository that will lead to memory or storage problems.

A directory in a commit is a simple text file that references either other directories or files. In git the correct name for a directory is tree and for files blob.

Even a commit is a simple text file. You can show it's content using `cat-file -p`. E.g.

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
tree c1971b07ce6888558e2178a121804774c4201b17
parent 18ed56cbc5012117e24a603e7c072cf65d36d469
author Kate Murphy <hello@kate.io> 1507821911 -0400
committer GitHub <noreply@github.com> 1507821911 -0400

Update README.md
```

As you can see the commit contains a reference to the parent commit object and the root tree object. Now you should be able to explain why a commit gets another id when you change the author, committer or message or when you rebase it: Because the commits content changes and therefore the hash that git uses in the git database.

Back to the git bomb. The git bomb is a bomb, because of the de-duplication that reuses tree and blob objects.

The structure is:

```
 COMMIT (c1971b07)  -+-- tree (8d106ebc)  -+-- tree (5849ef74)  -+ tree(8f4c1eae)
                     |                     |                     .....
                     |                     |
                     |                     |
                     |                     +-- tree (5849ef74)  -+ tree(8f4c1eae)
                     |                     ....                 ....
                     +   tree (8d106ebc)
                     |                     |
                     |                     |
                     |                     |
                     |                     +-- tree (5849ef74)
                     |                     ....                            
                     +   tree (8d106ebc)  -+-- tree (5849ef74)
                     ....                  ...
```

The same tree object is re-used again and again. Therefore the git repository keeps small.

But in the git bomb repository the first tree level (the root) contains 10 subtrees. Each of the subtrees contains 10 subtrees and so on. The whole nesting level is 10 and each of the deepest tree objects contain 10 blobs (All the same object).

Thus when you try to checkout this repository git must create 10^10= 10000000000 directories in the file system and each of this directories has 10 files. So the leafs of this tree is 100.000.000.000. I guess a lot of file systems will surrender if you try to create 100.000.000.000 files + the directories.

**Conclusion**
I don't really understand what the intention of a git bomb repository is, except to find a way to make a repository unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Here, "de-duplicates" is a verb, not an adjective. Deduplication is when you have two of the same thing, and instead just store it once.

In this case, if I check the file `100MBFile.txt` into a Git repository, then `git` will store it as a blob. If I copy the file ten times into ten different parts of the repository, it will still only be stored once in the `.git` folder, even if it's stored multiple times in the working directory.

Git also deduplicates trees (how it represents directories), allowing you to get even more copies of a file without looking like it.

That means that you can get a very small Git repository which ends up very large when you actually check out a branch.

For more information on blobs, trees, and deduplication, check out [the Git Book section on Git objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).